# How to generate react html in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay so this is has been driving me mad for the past few hours. Pretty much i want to have a function that generates html based off of objects in an array that are passed to it as an argument. My Code looks something like this:

```
handleEvents = (array) => {
if(array.length > 0){
  array.forEach(function(each){
    return(<h1>hello {each.name}</h1>)
  })
}
```

And in my render component i have this:

```
<div className="caption left-align">
  <h3>Upcoming events</h3>
    {this.handleEvents([{name: "Dave"}, {name: "Mary"}, {name: "Chris"}])}
 </div>
```

But when i run this code nothing is being output to the screen. What should i do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you go through the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and frame your question in a better way to reflect the problem. You can refer [this helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem is that `Arrays.forEach` does not return anything. If you change your handleEvents function to look more like

```
if(array.length > 0){
  return array.map(function(each){
    return(<h1>hello {each.name}</h1>)
  })
} else {
  return []
}
```

This should return an h1. The map function will return a list of the elements returned

Answer (score 3):

Or using `forEach`

```
 handleEvents = (array) => {
 if(array.length > 0){
  let tempArray = []
  array.forEach(function(each){
    tempArray.push(<h1>hello {each.name}</h1>)
 })
  return tempArray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use expression function while using array.map(). Changing the code by replacing anonymous function with expression function like below we can achieve the same.

```js
array.length > 0 ?
   array.map((item, index) => {
      return (
         <li className="list-item" key={index}>{item.Title}</li>
        );
      }) :  "No item found."
```

Answer (score 0):

[forEach function return undefines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Therefore, your code does not show anything. You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function which creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
if(array.length > 0){
  return array.map(function(each){
    return(<h1>hello {each.name}</h1>)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display some markup for each element of the array (without extra logic) you can use `map` directly in your `jsx` in `render`. Here is an example:

```
render() {
    const array = [{name: "Dave"}, {name: "Mary"}, {name: "Chris"}];

    return (<div className="caption left-align">
      <h3>Upcoming events</h3>
      {array && array.map((el) => <h1>hello {el.name}</h1>)}
    </div>);
}
```

You don't have to check if `array.length` is bigger than `0` since if the array is empty nothing will be rendered anyway so the check will be redundant. You might however check if it is not `null` or `undefined` (checked for `truthy` in the example above) because if it is and you try to invoke `map` on it, the code will throw an exception.